# Excel - Drop down list within a formula

Tags: if-statement, lookup

I am sure this is a easy formula but 1 am struggling, I have the following:

On tab 1 I want to enter a colour multiple times into column A using a drop down option, for example and I want to pull the how many information from a table on another sheet, so when I do my formula using xlookup (`=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:A7,Sheet2!B2:B7)`) it works for the top 4 options but not the rest. Can someone help? I ahve also tried the IF formula etc but with no success.

```
A       B
Colours How Many
Black   17
Yellow  765
Purple  65
Orange  43
Red     #N/A
Green   #N/A
Purple  #N/A
Orange  #N/A
```

Sheet 2 table:

```
Colors  How Many
Red     34
Black   17
Green   32
Yellow  765
Purple  65
Orange  43
```

I hope this make sense.

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7, 2, FALSE)
```